# Check if row of specific id appears earlier in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of customer orders which is something like below:

```
order_id | customer_id |    date    | ...
-----------------------------------------
   583         192       2015-05-01   ...
   734         143       2015-06-04   ...
   801         455       2015-07-02   ...
   ...         ...           ...      ...
```

I want to find how many *new customers I receive in a given month*. A new customer can be found by querying the orders table above and finding the number of `customer_id` values that appear in that month but do not appear before that month (after that month is fine). I'm looking for the first instance of a new `customer_id`.

Is there a way to do this in one SQL statement? I could do something like the below I think:

- get all `order_id` and `DISTINCT customer_id` from a month by querying database using `LIKE YYYY-MM-%`
- check the table for instances of `customer_id` with a smaller `order_id` (it stands to reason a smaller `order_id` will be an earlier order)
- if found, skip
- if not found, increment a counter

Comment: you want unique users, you don't need to loop thru all the results just use group by and get the unique ones. also, you're just counting them so it really doesn't make a difference if you're counting the first one or a subsequent one, just count the unique ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `date_From` is your period start date and `date_To` is period end date you can do it something like:

```
select distinct T1.customer_id
from your_table as T1
    left outer join your_Table as T2 on 
       T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id and T2.date < date_From
where
    T1.date <= date_To
    and T1.date >= date_From
    and T2.customer_id is null
```

Here joining to the same table using same `customer_id` and date prior to your period and checking that join has no result (by `T2.customer_id is null`) ensures your `customer_id` first appears in the order of your period and not earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This will list your new customers in January, 2016

```
select customer_id,order_id from customer c 
where MONTHNAME(date) = 'January' and YEAR(date) = 2016
    and date >= 
(select min(date) mindate from customer c1 
where c.customer_id = c1.customer_id 
having MONTH(c.date) <> MONTH(c1.mindate) or YEAR(c.date) <> YEAR(c1.
mindate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need order_id, if you need to count customers. All you need is customer_id and date:

```
select count(*) from 
    ( select min(date) as first_contact, customer_id 
      from the_table 
      group by customer_id )  new_customers
where  new_customers.first_contact > start_of_the_month 
   and new_customers.first_contact < end_of_the_month
```